# ArcGIS Android Studio Falied to resolve: com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.8-1

Tags: android, gradle, arcgis

I am having the following issue when trying to sync my android app's gradle script:

> Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.8-1

After reading a few sites and trying to apply their solutions but the error keeps showing up, I also tried using a different version of the dependency and it still not works.

Here is my build.gradle (Module:app) file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.alejandrorodriguez.demoapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.8-1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My build.gradle (Module:TestApp) file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://esri.bintray.com/arcgis'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks for your time to help me :)

Comment: I don't think this will fix it, but delete the `maven` `url` reference in `buildscript`. It doesn't go there. You only need it in `allprojects`.

Comment: It won't, i actually added the maven url in the buildscript because i read somewhere that it would fix it.

Comment: Ok, i added a facebook dependency to the build.gradle and the problem is with all the marven dependencies, no just with esri.

Comment: I fixed the error, the problem was that android studio didn't updated the gradle.properties file when i changed the proxy, so i had to manually edit the file. Now it's working properly.